# Traffic not seen as interesting over tunnel

Tags: vpn, cisco-ios, ipsec

I have an issue where traffic is no longer passing over the tunnel.

Below is my config and I can not get access to the other side due to not being allowed.  I just need to make sure my config is right so the other chaps keep looking at their side.

When I do the following:

```
show crypto isakmp sa
```

I get:

**peer peer QM_IDLE           2019 ACTIVE**

```
crypto isakmp policy 1
encr 3des
authentication pre-share
group 2
crypto isakmp key 12345678 address 111.111.111.111

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
mode tunnel
crypto ipsec df-bit clear

crypto map SDM_CMAP_1 1 ipsec-isakmp 
description Tunnel to 111.111.111.111
set peer 111.111.111.111
set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA 
match address 100

interface Vlan1
description $FW_INSIDE$
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
no ip redirects
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
ip tcp adjust-mss 1412

interface Dialer0
description $FW_OUTSIDE$
ip address negotiated
no ip redirects
ip mtu 1452
ip nat outside
ip virtual-reassembly in
encapsulation ppp
dialer pool 1
dialer-group 1
ppp authentication chap callin
ppp chap hostname me@direct.telstra.net
ppp chap password 0 123456
crypto map SDM_CMAP_1

ip nat inside source route-map SDM_RMAP_1 interface Dialer0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer0 permanent

access-list 1 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.173.0 0.0.0.255
route-map SDM_RMAP_1 permit 1
```

I just can not see what I am missing as traffic falls in the range of the access list but when I do a show ip access=list the counters don't increase.

Any ideas as I can not reach 192.168.173.0 network?

Comment: What do you mean "no longer passing through tunnel?"  What changed?

Comment: Far end router was rebooted so I am 99% sure its not my problem but I can not get access to the other router as not allowed.  I just need to know if my config is correct and if I have missed something.

Comment: Follow up question on my comment, should the show ip access-list counts increase if I try ping 192.168.173.0 network as they are not incrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I was suspecting a NAT issue as traffic for 192.168.173.0 was going out into the internet.

Here is extra code that ensures traffic for the VPN is not NATTED.

```
access-list 101 deny   ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.173.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
route-map SDM_RMAP_1 permit 1
 match ip address 101
```